# Tailwind classes act differently on local host and on demo and main branch after build and deploy

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react project, and I'm creating a className for a div using classname package and tailwind classes. This div is actually the root element of a component that has some classes and accepts some from outside. The final class looks like below:

```bash
class="flex-1 bg-white border p-8 mb-6 rounded-md tracking-wide mt-1 !mb-0 md:mb-6 !bg-transparent md:bg-white border-0 md:border-1 !p-0 md:!p-6 tracking-wide relative"
```

It works fine when I test it on my local branch and the bottom margin is zero. But when I push it to my main branch and it builds what I see on the browser is different. The '!mb-0' got overridden and the mb-6 still shows. This problem is repeated everywhere.

Is there a way to avoid this so what we see on the local host acts exactly like the one on the main branch and demo after deploy?

This is how the margin classes look like after deploy

[image]

Comment: Maybe you just need to clean up your css classes and only state one `mb` instead of trying to overwrite something

Comment: Show what the css looks like for this item in dev tools.

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski I added the picture you needed.

Comment: This div is actually the root element of a component that has some classes and accepts some from outside.

Comment: When you start using `important` in css or in tailwind it means you are doing something wrong. You shouldn't add multiple classes that can do the same like this. The only thing that determines what class should be assigned is the order in the output css file. Please add classes conditionally and make some variants.

Comment: Very strange that `.mb-6` has `!important` attached to it. Does it have that on your local branch?

Comment: @stickyuser yes it does have. But it seems in the local branch the priority of classes gets considered so because  !mb-0 is after mb-6 margin becomes zero.